Blazor app exception when running on Linux
I have a Blazor Web App running on ASP.NET Core 8.0. It runs fine on my dev environment (Visual Studio 2022 on Windows 11), but when I publish it to a Ubuntu server, an exception is thrown when doing some actions in the application. Most of the application works fine though.
Exception:
Unhandled exception rendering component: Could not resolve type with token 01000011 from typeref (expected class 'System.Attribute' in assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a') assembly:System.Runtime, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a type:System.Attribute member:(null)
System.TypeLoadException: Could not resolve type with token 01000011 from typeref (expected class 'System.Attribute' in assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a') assembly:System.Runtime, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a type:System.Attribute member:(null)

I don't understand why version 7.0 of .NET is referenced (I suspect this to be the issue?). I couldn't find any reference to it in my code. The application used to run on .NET 7, but I moved it to .NET 8 a while ago. I also removed the .NET runtime version 7.0 from the Ubuntu server, but it didn't fix the issue.

If you go to the bin directory of your app, you will find a .deps.json file
e.g .\MyBlazorApp\bin\Debug\net8.0\MyBlazorApp.deps.json
This file shows ALL dependencies of your app. Maybe you can find the faulty reference to the 7.0 assembly in there.
Also make sure that there are no old versions of this file on your Ubuntu server.

Thanks for the hints, I didn't know about the deps file. I didn't find any suspiscious file though. After more invistigation, I still didn't find the origin of the issue. But I finally rebuilt the solution and redeployed, and now it works!
